# Outlook.MailItem - The Operation Failed

Tags: .net, email, frameworks, outlook

We have many VB.NET application which open a new Outlook Message.  The various applications being written in .NET 2.5, 3.5 and 4.5... **all of which are now having an issue... but had previously been running fine for years.**

When the Outlook message is shown, after entering a TO address, then clicking 'Send', the following error is given: "The Operation Failed".

[image: OutlookError]

Here is the code...

```
    Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim oEmail As Outlook.MailItem
    oApp = New Outlook.Application
    oEmail = oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)
    oEmail.Display()
```

However, there is nothing to debug in the code, because once the outlook message is displayed, it's out of the control of the Visual Studio application.

- This is happening to about 10 of our 40 users.
- Some running Windows 7 32 bit, others running Windows 7 64 bit.
- Clicking "New Message" directly from outlook, allows the emails to be
  sent successfully.
- Nothing is logged in the System / Windows Event Logs.
- All Windows Updates on our working systems are also showing on the
  systems having the issue.
- This is happening to users running both Outlook 2010 or Outlook 2013

A side note...

- While Person A is logged into PC 1, the issue occurs.
- If Person B logs into PC 1, no error.
- If Person A logs into PC 2, no error.

This led us to look towards the profile, rather than the specifics of the PC.

Comment: Before doing `oEmail.Display()` what happens if you call `oEmail.Save()`?

Comment: One other thing I can think of is that some users have anti-virus software that is interfering with normal operations. Would be curious to turn off A/V on a system where this problem exists and then see if it is still a problem.

Comment: @MichaelPetch We have just disabled all Anti-Virus and also Windows Defender.. but no success... still having the same issue.  I'll post with an update on Monday about the oEmail.Save(), everyone having the issue leaves for the weekend in 3 minutes... and it's not happening on my PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well we can't say we know what caused the problem, but we did find a solution just last night.  Still very strange that this suddenly started happening to about 15% of our users.

1. Delete the users Roaming Profile on their PC (while logged in as administrator)
2. Have the user log in again
3. Control Panel -> Mail -> Show Profiles
4. Delete the record
5. Add a new record

This does have some unfortunate side effects...

- The users desktop items are all rearranged
- The users homepage & favorites are gone
- The network printers need to be added back in
- Certain locally installed programs need to be "setup" the first time again